# How to save a List with another List inside to a file

Tags: c#, list, file, save, streamwriter

So I have my user object:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

And as you can see, I have a List of projects that belongs to the user.
To save my user, I did this function:

```
    public void AddNewUser(UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            string folder = @"c:\temp\";
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter($"{folder}input.txt", append: true);

            sw.WriteLine($"{user.Id}," +
                $"{user.Username}");

            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The file could not be read: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
```

But now I Have this question, how can I save the List of projects and associate to the user.
I know I can save every project to another file or save to the same file, but how can I relate them?

Comment: You might want to consider XML or JSON serialization.

Comment: You can use `XML` or `CSV` (although that will add redundancy), but why do you want to save to a file. This is exactly what databases are for.

Comment: Ideally, this should be in a Database all along. That is literally what they were designed for. 1 Table Users. 1 Table Projects. 1 Table to resolve the N:M called UserProjects | Failing that, XML is propably the next best bet. CSV does not deal that well with Nested Lists, but for XML they are as normal as the pointy bracket. JSON also works and is a lot less verbose then XML

Comment: You have multiple options but the answer really depends on your requirements. The solution that provides quickest implementation (csv with redundant data) will probably work now but very soon you will encounter more issues that could have been prevented by avoiding the quick solution. The long term solution (database) may be overkill for what you ultimately are trying to accomplish. The way I see it your options are; single file CSV with repeating data, two CSV files with related key field, a single XML or JSON file, or two tables in a database with a foreign key. What is your goal here?

Comment: Thank you all!
I ended up using Json Serialization.